# Create new row with a one new value based on value in another row

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, sql-insert, sql-server-2019-express

What I have:

| VALUE | PROPERTY | HOST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | Dave |
| Two | 2 | Dave |
| Three | 3 | Dave |

What I want to achieve:

| VALUE | PROPERTY | HOST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 1 | Dave |
| Two | 2 | Dave |
| Three | 3 | Dave |
| One | 1 | Pete |
| Two | 2 | Pete |
| Three | 3 | Pete |

So I'm trying to create new rows based on any rows that have Dave as the host.   Those rows are identical to the Dave rows except the Host is Pete.  The Dave rows are retained.  The Pete rows are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `VALUES` table construct with both Dave and John in the data:

```sql
SELECT YT.Value,
       YT.Property,
       V.Host
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Dave'),
                        ('Pete'))V(Host)
WHERE YT.Host = 'Dave';
```

Comment: A bit of a nitpick, you could've done VALUES(YT.HOST), ('Pete')

Comment: I was also tempted to parametrise, @siggemannen . There's a few different ways you can "skin the cat" here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `INSERT INTO` combined with a `SELECT` should do the trick.

```
INSERT INTO
  dbo.tablename (VALUE, PROPERTY, HOST)
SELECT
  VALUE, PROPERTY, 'Pete'
FROM
  dbo.tablename
WHERE
  HOST = 'Dave'
```